# Test.Error Expected status code 200 but received 200.How to fix it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

I created test for CompanyController,

```
public function testCompanyIndex()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'web')->get('company/index');
        $response->assertStatus('200');
    }
```

but i have an error:

> 1) Tests\Feature\CompanyTest::testCompanyIndex
>       Expected status code 200 but received 200.
>       Failed asserting that false is true.

In CompanyController i have middleware `auth:web`.`CompanyController@index` returns all Companies.

Comment: just remove '' like this  $response->assertStatus(200);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove quotes like this `$response->assertStatus(200);`
for more details click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests)

Comment: Ok, but how can i know that page was downloaded?